# Errors using curl for nutch RESTapi calls

Tags: http, curl, nutch, nutch2

I am using curl to make RESTapi calls to my nutch server running on a ubuntu instance. When I make the following call with curl to create my seeds file on my server

`curl -X POST http://**.185.***.**:8081/seed/create -d {"id": "ubuntu", "name": "servertest1", "seedUrls": [{"id":1,"seedList":null,"url":"http://www.******.com/"}]}`

I receive the following error

```
The given resource variant is not supported.Please use one of the following:

* Variant[mediaType=application/json, language=null, encoding=null]
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ubuntu,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: name
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: servertest1,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: seedUrls
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range in column 2
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range in column 2
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range in column 2
```

Thanks for your help in advance, I'm new to HTTP calls so I'm very lost

Comment: Looks like the command isn't properly escaped: you need to put quotes around the `-d` argument: `curl ... -d '{"id": ... }'`

Comment: That worked for most of the errors, now I'm just getting 

`
The given resource variant is not supported.Please use one of the following:

* Variant[mediaType=application/json, language=null, encoding=null]
`
But I'm pretty sure its proper json formatting so I don't know why I'm receiving that error